# How do I add an editable navigation bar to my iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift

What I mean is a static "top-bar" that I can edit from the relevant swift file.

I don't actually want any of the navigation function, but I want to be able to change what it says situationally.

I've looked around quite a bit but can't seem to find a solution for this seemingly simple task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The navigation bar automatically picks up the UIViewController's title property. You could just set that value.

Comment: since you don't need any navigation function, create your own view and make it look like top bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a pretty easy, but not straightforward solution...

All I had to do was

1. Add a navigation bar, by clicking Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller
2. The hard to find part, use the property `self.navigationItem.title = "title"` to change the title.

The second part I found from hgwhittle's answer in this question, which also covers how to change the nav bar title, the tab bar title, or both.

[UIViewController Title attribute in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844997/uiviewcontroller-title-attribute-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, if this is what you want. 
However, if you want a navigation bar with customizable navigation item title/text, then you can just add Navigation Item from the Object library to your Navigation bar.

Then in the inspector, you can select custom and specify the title of that navigation item as you desire. You can also create an IBOutlet for it and change the title in your code in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl Drag the bar button from the storyboard to the appropriate view controller implementation file. I.e viewController.h. This will create an IBAction, which you can name.

```
- (IBAction)nameOfAction:(id)sender {
  // Action goes here
}
```

Any logic applied inside will be called on button press.